# jQuery Chosen Css Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I having an issue of using it on my post_form page in my admin panel for the Client: field. It works on my artist_form for clients, but in the inspector of my browsers it is showing an error on the post_form page. The first screenshot is from the post_form with the error, the second is from the artist_form where I have your fine plugin working, and the third which I am unable to post being I don't have enough reputation here as I am new to this site would be from my header.php where the link to the chosen.css file is posted. If you can assist me with resolving this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

[The first screenshot is from the post_form with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2C7i.png)

[the second is from the artist_form where I have the plugin working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmzmh.png)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
// Post Form Validate
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#postForm').validate({
   errorElement: "div",
   rules: {
       name: { required: true },
       details: { required: true },
       category: { required: true }
     }
  });
  $('#restform').click(function(){
            $('#postForm')[0].reset();
   });
 });
// Chosen multi-select
 var config = {
 '.chosen-select' : {},
 '.chosen-select-deselect' : {allow_single_deselect:true},
 '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
 '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
 '.chosen-select-width' : {width:"95%"}
 }
 for (var selector in config) {
 $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
 } 
</script>
```

```css
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>World Music Listing: Master Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/chosen.css">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/pro_dropline_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--  jquery core -->
<script src="public/js/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="public/js/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

```html
     <tr>     
      <th valign="top">Client:</th>
      <td>
      <?php 
       $host_name = "localhost";
       $database = "#my database name";   
       $username = "#my admin user name";         
       $password = "#my password for the admin user";          

       //////// Do not Edit below /////////
       try {
        $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
       }
       // Select all artists (clients) and order by name //
       $sql="SELECT aname FROM tbl_music_artists ORDER BY aname";
       // multi-select dropdown - select which artists (clients) receive posts //
      ?> 
       <select name="userids[]" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Client..." style="width:350px;" multiple>
      <?php 
       foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){
       echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[aname]</option>";
       }
      ?>
       </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by copy and re-pasting the <script type="text/javascript">
        var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    ...
</script> code at the bottom of my post_form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by copy and re-pasting the  var config = { '.chosen-select' : {}, '.chosen-select-deselect' : {allow_single_deselect:true}, '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10}, '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'}, '.chosen-select-width' : {width:"95%"} } ...  code at the bottom of my post_form which came from the chosen jquery.